# How to add odd/even class to wrapping divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to build a page where I want to wrap each component inside a div which either has an "odd" or "even" class so that I can set different background-colors. I'm pretty new to `gatsby` and `react` so I wonder how to do that?

I followed the instructions how to set up an `gatsby`-project [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-one/#install-the-hello-world-starter) and this is what I got so far:

index.js:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div className="page-container">
    <component-1 />
    <component-2/>
    <component-3/>
    <component-4/>
    <component-5/>
 </div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

what I want is something like this

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <div className="page-container">
    <div className="odd">
       <component-1 />
    </div>
    <div className="even">
       <component-2 />
    </div>
    <div className="odd">
       <component-3 />
    </div>
    <div className="even">
       <component-4 />
    </div>
 </div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

I just called my components silly names for display reasons...

How can I achive this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding classNames to odd and even elements in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254504/adding-classnames-to-odd-and-even-elements-in-reactjs)

Comment: any specific reason for not just using nth child css selector?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yes, that would also be a possibility :)

Comment: Unless you need the class names for something other than CSS you can just use the `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors.